# Customizable option price not updated to cart

Tags: magento2, cart, price, custom-options

I have aaded some custom option like

[image]

When i checked the checkbox on product details page it shows price less than 200 but when i hit add to cart it added the normal price of product not the price with -200.

Any one have any idea regarding this any help is appriciated.

Answer (score 1):

This scenario will not work with minus numbers

Comment: Thanks for your response @eifling. If i want to work it with minus values too how to work with it ?

Comment: You'd have to think about it the other way round.

So if treat the product price as 0 - but you customise it to add $200. In this case you would add 0. But your other options may add $200

Example. 
Product price: 0
Add Installation: $200
No Installation: 0